# handling certificates in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to automate angularjs application using protractor which asks to select a certificate to authenticate as shown below.

Certificate for authentication:

[image]

I am unable to interact with it by following below ways.

```
1.  browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
2.  browser.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(keys.ENTER);
3.  browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
4.  using Robot class as we do in webdriver
```

I am not able to proceed until I crosses this authentication. Once the certificate is selected it prompts to enter some PIN as shown in attachment.

Authentication using PIN:

[image: Authentication using PIN].

Comment: Is this web-based certificate ? IS there some html code to it?

Comment: No html code. I am not able to inspeact anything.

Comment: Can we use Auto It as we do in webdriver ?

Comment: Try using ESCAPE or TAB  key. Robot class won't work here in protractor

Comment: No luck....! ESCAPE or TAB key also not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That is the best way to deal with windows-based pop-ups